# Inconsistent issues with keyboard since a windows update and a new mouse

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse

I have a laptop on windows 10, and recently I have been adding a new wireless USB mouse (logitech) and performing a windows update 18362.356. Recently I have updated NordVPN also.

Since this moment I have an issue - often inconsistent- with my built-in keyboard.
I would rather think it's not a mechanical issue for these reasons : 
- it's only some parts which are not working : so far letter 'D', backspace and main "return/enter" touch, not the one on the numerical pad.
- It can be lagging for a long time (I can type one of the non functioning one for 5 sec and all of a sudden it works for a different amount of time) or not working at all
- one way to 'unfreeze' my keyboard is to .. plug a USB connector of a mouse for instance, it unfreezes for a while, sometimes for seconds or for minutes

I tried to install last updates of mouse, keyboard, windows10.. 
I tried to uninstall my keyboard drives and reboot.. doesn't work

At the same time I do sometimes have an issue in rebooting, telling me with a balck and white screen " status 0xc0000102 An unexpected error has occured". I trun off the computer and on, and then can reboot. This is a new behaviour concomittent to the keyboard issue.

An external USB keyboard is fully functioning.

I'm actually lost in what to do to clear this issue, I have an important research paper to write and it is very annoying :(

If you have any idea, please drop a line !

thanks

Comment: Error code 0xc0000102 means a corrupt file and its name should be inside the message, so please add it to the post. I would counsel to run [chkdsk](https://ss64.com/nt/chkdsk.html) to verify the disk. Run first `chkdsk` without parameters (or only with the disk-letter) to verify. If errors are found, before running `chkdsk /f`, take good backups.

Comment: Hi, no actually before that I just have the message windows failed to start, a recent hardware or software change might be the cause... and I have 1. insert your windows installation disc and restart etc. etc.
by the way should I run it on windows or on a "dos-like" approach? It seems that I can't have access to it on windows. Is there a "sudo" like?

Comment: `chkdsk` is a Command Prompt utility.

Comment: Thanks :) still says that I don't have permission although I'm admin

Comment: Run the Command Prompt as Admin. By default it doesn't have elevated permissions.